# C# - nested using statements redundant?

Tags: c#, filestream, dispose, streamreader, using

I came across the following example code in the MSDN documentation, demonstrating the use of the `System.IO.StreamReader` class to read UTF-8 text from a `System.IO.FileStream` object. The two nested `using` statements struck me as redundant - surely calling `Dispose()` on one of the objects does the trick, and properly releases the file handle? (Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhfzs7at.aspx)

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open)) 
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs)) 
    {

        while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
        }
    }
}
```

Would it not be simpler, and equally correct, to rewrite that code in the following way?

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open)) 
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);

    while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe it's a good idea to dispose all that implements `IDisposable`.

Comment: Similar question with good answers: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9949377/361684

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation, [The StreamReader object calls Dispose() on the provided Stream object when StreamReader.Dispose is called](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhfzs7at.aspx). This means `using` the `StreamReader` guarantees disposal of the underlying  `Stream`. It does not hold vice versa: disposing only the `Stream` **does not** suffice - the `StreamReader` may be allocating other native resources. So the second sample is not correct.

(`using` only the `StreamReader` does not cover the case that the `StreamReader` constructor can throw. To cover this case, both `using`'s would be needed. Since it only throws for non-readable or `null` streams, this  may not be relevant though.)

In general, you should always dispose on every disposable object. It is part of the `IDisposable` contract that it does not hurt to dispose an object multiple times, and the overhead of doing so is low.

Comment: Your quote is correct but does not relate to the 2nd code sample.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I am also saying that the second sample is for this very reason not correct.

Answer (score 3):

The second sample is simply wrong on principle.

It won't leak anything but that relies on the knowledge that a StreamReader has no resources of its own and does not actually needs Disposing even though it is IDisposable.

A single `using(){}` around the **`StreamReader`** would have been more or less correct here, based on the documented (and criticized) feature that the Reader will close its Stream.

The best practice here is to use 2 using statments.  Note that they are very cheap, and you simply want code that's consistent.

Comment: Note that `StreamReader` also provides an option to say *don't close the underlying stream*. Also single using statement only in `StreamReader` is a problem when its constructor throws, `FileStream` will not be closed.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - as of Fx 4.5, yes. But that is not the cotor being used here.

Comment: True, I'm adding to say there is an option to leave the stream open. Btw I edited my previous comment to point that single using statement around StreamReader will be dangerous.

Comment: That argument about throwing is very generic and does not apply to this code fragment. I wouldn't encourage the single using but not fault it either in this  case.